# How do I measure percent CPU usage using prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, cpu, cpu-usage

I’m trying to use the prometheus measurements to get percent CPU usage for each micro service running in Kubernetes to optimize CPU resources and limits.

I have a setup where for each customer there are 4 micro services running on the server.  Each micro service has a separate memory resource and limit and separate CPU resource and limit.  To get the average from prometheus I am using the following query:

avg_over_time(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~"^k8s_.*", namespace=~"$namespace", container_name!="POD", pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}[5m]))[24h:5m]) /
avg_over_time(sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{name=~"^k8s_.*", namespace=~"$namespace",container_name!="POD", pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"}/container_spec_cpu_period{name=~"^k8s_.*",namespace=~"$namespace", container_name!="POD", pod=~"^$Deployment.*$"})[24h:5m]) * 100

To check that the value above is correct, I go into each Kubernetes pod and check the CPU usage using the command:
kubectl -n {namespace} top pod {Deployment}

To check the CPU limit I use the command:
kubectl -n {namespace} describe pod {Deployment}

Where I get the CPU limit.

Then I do the calculation:
CPU usage divided by CPU limit times 100 equals current percent of CPU usage.

The values I get from the CPU usage and limit in Kubernetes are different from the values I get using the prometheus query (Some of the values I get are close and some are quite off).
Here is an example of CPU usage in Percent from Prometheus and from Kubernetes:

| Customer | Service | Prometheus | Kubernetes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | Service 1 | 0.216 | 0.2 |
|  | Service 2 | 0.137 | 0.2 |
|  | Service 3 | 0.445 | 0.45 |
|  | Service 4 | 0.165 | 0.2 |
|  |  |  |  |
| Customer B | Service 1 | 0.139 | 0.2 |
|  | Service 2 | 0.0917 | 0.2 |
|  | Service 3 | 0.5739 | 0.5 |
|  | Service 4 | 0.0972 | 0.2 |

Anyone have any comments whether I am doing the measurements correctly? Is there a mistake in my prometheus query or how I get the values from Kubernetes? I want to make sure that I am measuring the percent CPU usage correctly using prometheus

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query for one service and modify the query according your requirement:

sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores) * 100

I also track the CPU usage for each pod.

sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name) I have a complete kubernetes-prometheus solution on GitHub,
maybe can help you with more metrics: [https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes.](https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes)

I hope this will help! The result is pretty much the same as the Windows performance manager. So, for CPU % for running services (tasks, processes):

sum by (process,hostname)(irate(wmi_process_cpu_time_total{scaleset="name", process=~